# Should I use NI Measurement Studio or niDAQms for my VB.NET windows GUI app?

Tags: c#, vb.net, labview, daq-mx, measurement-studio

I need to create a VB.NET GUI to manage a National Instruments (NI) USB-6343 instrument.

Should I use the NI Measurement Studio or niDAQms API?

My GUI requirements are:
- command the 6343 to input analog values
- command it to control output analog value
- chart the input analog value over time.

I'm using Visual Studio VB.NET 2017 PRO on Windows-7 desktop and Windows-10 laptop.

Comment: Just to clarify: The driver/API is called NI-DAQmx. To communicate with the device you'll use it in one form or another regardless of what your GUI looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This highly depends on the functionality you need to add later on. Both the options are possible, directly calling the ni-DAQmx API or create the VB.net code via the measurement studio.

From practical point of view I would suggest that you create the VB.net code from the measurement studio via the solution explorer with the basic measurements you want. Than copy that code to visual studio and use the API for the rest of the work where needed.

This should give you the efficiency benefits of using the measurement studio and latter the flexibility of using the API and visual studio.

Comment: So, Measurement Studio is the fastest way to get general control of my NI 6343, and straight NI-DAQmx gives me fullest control.  Right?